# Can I validate a form in spring mvc without using anotation?

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I read some document on the Internet about form validation in Spring MVC. And I don't know what happend if I use only Java core code (don't use anotation and something like BindingResult, hasError()...) for validation). Is there any convention that we must use anotation for validation.
For example, I use Java core code in my Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member, Model model) {
       if("".equals(member.getUsername()){
           model.addAttribute("error", "username is empty");
       }
       return "login";
    }
```

And then I show error in my login.jsp file.

I'm a fresher java web developer, please explain it to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do without using annotations, but I believe it would be like taking the long way around, as annotations are made to ease the validation process.

there is the JSR 380 specification, it greatly simplifies your validation work.

please read this: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

having understood what javax validation is, you can implement validations directly in your java classes, and in the controller you can validate using @Valid, as in the following example:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String showLogin(@Valid Member member, Errors errors, Model model) {
   if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
   return "login";
}
```

this way, spring will validate your 'member' class and if it contains any errors, it will return the error messages to the page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to use validation and it's really convenient with simple condition like not null, size, min, max. But with custom condition, I see it's more complex. May be, I'm not used to using it ^^^

Comment: yes, it really is a bit of work, but it is necessary, so that your code becomes simpler and easier to understand in the future, it is necessary to evolve :)
if you do the validations manually, it will take a lot of time and be more difficult to maintain.